# Jquery modal dialog not showing title bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I work on .NET project, VS 2015, MVC.

I am trying to open modal dialog with jQuery-UI.

Dialog opens, but I am not able to see title bar or anything else, connected with dialog design. Close button on the dialog is working normally.

Code for opening:

```
var OpenModal = function () {

  var page = "/UserAvailability/EventUsers/";

  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                 .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                 .dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true,
                   height: 700,
                   width: "90%",
                   title: "Dodaj uporabnike na dogodek",
                   open: function () {
                     $(this).find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').blur();
                   },
                 })

  $dialog.dialog('open');

};
```

Here is how dialog looks after opening:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Styles that I have included in bundle:

```
 StyleBundle stylesAll = new StyleBundle("~/styles/all");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/bootstrap.min.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/datepicker3.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/bootstrap-timepicker.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/jquery.ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/common.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/style/bootstrap-custom.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/jquery.ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
  stylesAll.Include("~/static/jquery.ui/css/smoothness/jquery.ui.theme.css");
```

Scripts included in bundle:

```
  ScriptBundle scriptsAll = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/all");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/jquery.ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/bootstrap.min.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/json3.min.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/jquery.cookie.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js");
      scriptsAll.Include("~/static/scripts/common.js");
```

Comment: Looks like you have 5 different style sheets loading for jQuery UI. I suspect something is conflicting. When you inspect it in browser, do you see any of the styles being knocked out?

Comment: @Twisty - yes, I see quite a lot of them striked. But how to check which style is overriding which?

Comment: When a property is set, it can be over written by the same property further down. So `.ui-dialog-titlebar` may be set in the custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.custom.css and then may be reset in any of the following sheets. Which did you intend to use?